# Difference between $this->paginate() and $this->Paginator->paginate()

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Aside from syntax, what are the difference between using `$this->paginate()` and `$this->Paginator->paginate()` in CakePHP 2?

Is there any advantage on using one over the other?

Answer (score 4):

It's [open source, you can take a](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.x/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php#L1106) look:

```
public function paginate($object = null, $scope = array(), $whitelist = array()) {
    return $this->Components->load('Paginator', $this->paginate)->paginate($object, $scope, $whitelist);
}
```

So controller's `paginate()` is just a wrapper. The benefit is that controller method seems to load `Paginator` component, so your controller can skip explicit loading.

Answer (score 1):

`Controller::paginate()` method uses `Controller::$paginate` property.

> Controller::$paginate was specifically removed in favor of using the PaginatorComponent.

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/857#issuecomment-8670695

`PaginatorComponent::paginate()` method uses `PaginatorComponent::$paginate` property. If you need to use the pagination in multiple methods in the same controller and you need to use different pagination settings then it is better to paginate using the component.

In any case [Don’t mix controller and component pagination](http://www.dereuromark.de/2013/07/30/cakephp-tips-summer-2013/#don%E2%80%99t-mix-controller-and-component-pagination).

> ... if you mix controller pagination setup and call the Pagination component then, it can easily backfire as the two different
>   settings are not always merged as you would expect it to